# Netbeans 6.8 C++ IDE: program crashes while debugging in cygwin on windows

Tags: c++, netbeans, debugging, crash

Whenever I try to debug my project in Netbeans 6.8 C++ IDE with cygwin on windows, it gives me the message window "Application crashed".(Netbeans IDE does not crash but only my program)There is no problem while running only, but while debugging, it crashes. Please help

Comment: Using an IDE that was primarily designed to develop Java apps doesn't sound like a good idea.  It has a crummy debugger if it doesn't step in and show you the problem when the program fails.

Comment: I am using Netbeans 6.5 ml for the last 2 years for C++. It has so advanced debugging tools. I never faced the problem. This is the first time.

Answer (score 0):

OK, Im having been trying to install the c/c++ plugin for netbeans IDE 6.9 using the instruction from the netbeans support and from this website:
http://royalexander.wordpress.com/2009/03/20/configuring-cygwin-cc-compiler-for-netbeans-65-under-windows/

so decided to use cygwin as the build engine.
the build was fine but it crashes when I run it.
So I dig and dig.  I even open up its location in my c drive and run it manually.
finally, I found this different error message:

"entry point cygwin_create_path could not be located in dynamic link library cygwin1.dll"

This narrows down the problem to cygwin
after googling, I found that it might be a compatibility issue with the new cygwin update 1.7
So I install the 1.5 version instead and it worked!!!
Here is how you can do it too:
download the older version off the cygwin website:the  setup_legacy.exe
run the .exe
make sure to change to a new root directory name (if you have 1.7 already) for the cygwin download as you will be prompted.
create a location for download cache inside that directory
once you chose a mirror you can
search for these in the development:

- –binutils
- –gcc core
- –gcc g++
- –gcc g77
- –gcc mingw core
- –gcc mingw g++
- –gcc mingw g77
- –gdb
- –make
- –mingw runtime

hit next to install the cygwin package

set the environment variable (thru advanced system setting for vista). under system variable 
add `C:\cygwin\bin;` to the path variable

open up netbeans and open new project c/c++ app
under tools chose options and click on the c/c++ to add host
add host.  Chose to path to the root location of cygwin and then bin 
make it default
it will have a name like cygwin_1 or whatever
ex: C:\cygwin_legacy\bin
netbeans will detect all compilers etc
OK the thing

Now 
right click on the project and hit property
click on build
to the right, change the tool collection to cygwin_1 (or whatever the name was)

write a hello world program (I did in c++)

debug and run the thing
It should work!
I hope this will help others like me in the future
I spent 4-5 hours over several days trying to figure this bug out.  It was hard because the error message was not helpful unless you run the .exe manually.  Only then you will get the entry point message.

Here is the build message (successful but crashed when run):

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Kelvin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppDebug'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/cppdebug.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Kelvin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppDebug'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o.d
g++-3.exe    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows
g++-3.exe     -o dist/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/cppdebug build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o  
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Kelvin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppDebug'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Kelvin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppDebug'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 24s)
```